# Reflect API and Serialization via JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reflection

The following JavaScript code does something I didn't expect.

```
let foo = {};
Reflect.defineProperty(foo,'bar',{value:1});
console.log(foo); // { bar: 1 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo)); // { }
```

Why is the serialized output from JSON.stringify missing the new bar property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because this property is not enumerable.

> By default, properties added using Object.defineProperty() are not writable, **not enumerable**, and not configurable.

see documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description

```js
let foo = {};
Reflect.defineProperty(foo,'bar',{value:1});

console.log( JSON.stringify(foo));             // {}
console.log( foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'))        // true
console.log( foo.propertyIsEnumerable('bar') ) // false
```

so you must do:

```js
let foo = {};
Reflect.defineProperty(foo,'bar',{enumerable: true, value:1});

console.log( JSON.stringify(foo));             // {"bar":1}
```

This is similar for the `length` property upon arrays:

```js
let arr = ['a','b','c']

console.log( arr.length )                         // 3
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr)  );  // [ "0", "1", "2", "length" ]
console.log( arr.hasOwnProperty('length'))        // true 
console.log( arr.propertyIsEnumerable('0') )      // true
console.log( arr.propertyIsEnumerable('length') ) // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```